# Direct Model.Property versus Html Helper DisplayFor in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a reason to use preferably one of these:

```
@Model.Property
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property)
```

I never arrived in a crossroad where one works differently from the other.

There is any difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Model.Property` - as you know - will just write out the value of the property in question. `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property)`, on the other hand, will call a display template, which can render out other markup around the property value.

For example, you might define a display template like so:

```
@model String

<div class="property-wrapper">
    <p>@Model.Property</p>
</div>
```

The surrounding divs will be rendered around the value of the property when using `DisplayFor` (if the display template is selected, which typically means it has a filename matching the property's type, is specified in the `UIHint` attribute for the property, or is explicitly specified in the call to `DisplayFor`.

You also have access to model metadata in your display templates, meaning you can do something like this:

```
<div class="property-label">
    @Html.DisplayNameForModel()
</div>

<div class="property-value">
    @Model.Property
</div>
```

Display templates give you a huge amount of flexibility and reusability. The best way to explore this is to start building custom templates and see where it takes you.